# HTML: render high resolution images in low resolution

Tags: html, image, image-processing

I have a folder with a bunch of images about 1080p in size. In that folder, I have an index.php that would display all the images, scaled down to 4 images per row. However, the images still render as if they were full size and resolution, so sometimes it takes a while to load all these images. I want to render the images, but in a lower resolution for faster loading times. Is this possible? Also, can it be done similarly with HTML 5's video element?

You can view the website where I want to load the images in lower quality at http://quantumquantonium.ddns.net/images_and_videos/screenshots/epic

Answer (score 0):

Use php imagick plugin in this case

Example :

```
<?php

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

$image = new Imagick('image.jpg');

// If 0 is provided as a width or height parameter,
// aspect ratio is maintained
$image->thumbnailImage(100, 0);

echo $image;

?>
```

Read more here : [php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php)

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible with html alone but with a php plugin you can transform the image size on the fly.

Comment: Ok... What is that plugin called?